# MapStruct: How to achieve NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT while mapping to a new Object

Tags: java, mapstruct

I want to map attributes in target object to default (e.g. String as "") if the corresponding attribute in source is null.
How can i achieve that ? I see that the

```
nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT
```

only works in case of update.

Is it possible to achieve something while creating the target object ?

Comment: Did you try anything with a sample object? A [example] would ease you to explain what you want and us to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set default values you need to use `Mapping#defaultValue` or `Mapping#defaultValueExpression`.

We currently do not support doing something similar to the `nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy`.

Another approach could be to use a custom `@ObjectFactory` that will set the default values in your object. You can read more about [Object Factories](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#object-factories) in the MapStruct documentation

One could also argue that default values should be set in the object construction.

Comment: The strategy behavior is explained on GitHub/MapStruct [issue 1909](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1909). Could you link some guides or references to study `@ObjectFactory` ?

Answer (score 3):

In following example the `name` attribute is mapped to default string `"Sample"`:

```java
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {
   @Mapping(source = "name", target = "name", defaultValue = "Sample")
   Car getModelFromEntity(CarEntity carEntity);
}
```

You can use the parameter `defaultValue` on the `@Mapping` annotation to map any `null` value attribute from the source to the specified default value on the target.

Comment: Maybe you incorporate this tutorial as a reference: [MapStruct - Using defaultValue](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mapstruct/mapstruct_using_defaultvalue.htm)

Answer (score 1):

### Default values at object instantiation

To assure default values for objects at initialization we can define them either in the constructor or at field declaration.

Example:

```java
class CarEntity {

    String type = "SUV"; // default set at declaration 
    String color; // default set in constructor
    String name; // no default, may be null!

    public CarEntity() {
        this.color = "black";  // default color set in constructor
    }
}
```

Here we have **preset defaults** for two fields (`type` and `color`).

If fields are **required** (as non-null) they should be declared `final` and either initialized directly or passed as constructor argument: e.g. the required field `final UUID id` can not have a default, it must be unique like `new CarEntity( UUID.randomUUID() )`.

Only optional and *nullable* field is `name`. It has no default and can be freely assigned a value from a mapping.

Let's see how we can use MapStruct to set a default value when mapped.

### Mapping to default values

When default values are set in the class already, the mapping can be simplified.

- we don't need to set fields at target to assure non-null values, they have preset defaults already
- all non-null values are mapped from source to target
- we only need to prevent a `null` value in respective source properties to overwrite the preset defaults in target

*MapStruct* may support this:

```java
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "type", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "name", defaultValue = "Sample")
    @Mapping(target = "color", condition = "isNotEmpty")
    CarEntity dtoToCarEntity(CarDTO car);

    @Condition
    default boolean isNotEmpty(String value) {
        return value != null && !value.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

How it works:

- the predefined default field `type` is completely ignored in mapping. It will not be mapped at all. So the default at target is preserved, not modified by mapping.
- the `name` field is set to default `"Sample"` if `null` in source. The default value can also be an empty String like [`defaultValue = ""`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#default-values-and-constants) or a [`defaultExpression`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#default-expressions) like for an ID field: `defaultExpression = "java( UUID.randomUUID().toString() )`.
- If the field `color` exists in source as `null` or empty String it will be ignored by the specified `condition = "isNotEmpty"` referencing the `@Conditional` predicate-method. See the MapStruct feature [issue-205](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2051).

#### Conditional mapping of properties

However in [10.10. Conditional Mapping](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#conditional-mapping) is explained that we can decide on property-mapping with a condition:

> A custom condition method is a method that is annotated with `org.mapstruct.Condition` and returns boolean.
>
> e.g. if you only want to map a String property when it is not `null, and it is not empty then you can do something like:

```java
    @Condition
    default boolean isNotEmpty(String value) {
        return value != null && !value.isEmpty();
    }
```

This will have the conditional effect we want, here for Strings:

- map only non-null) source-properties and ignore null/empty source-properties
- all target properties will be set to defaults during initialization

### Ignore strategies

Closely related to default values in mapping are the ignore-strategies. However they seem not applicable to creational mappings, but only on update (as of current version 1.5.0.Beta2).

#### Ignore `null` properties (currently on *update only*)

See *MapStruct Reference Guide*, [10.6. Controlling mapping result for 'null' arguments](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#mapping-result-for-null-properties).

Any annotation parameter `nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy` like `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE` or `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT` has no effect for creational mappings.

#### Ignore unmapped properties (and keep the preset defaults at target)

There are also strategies to completely **ignore unmapped properties**. See the tutorial on Baeldung: [Ignoring Unmapped Properties with MapStruct](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-ignore-unmapped-properties).

However this would turn our defaults into something like `final` fields, similar to constants. Defaults should are designed to be overwritten when more specific values are given.